# Web-based micro-transaction API

Tags: javascript, python, browser-based-games, microtransactions

I am currently making a browser-based game and I would like to integrate micro-transactions. However I would prefer not to have to implement my own storefront. Does anyone know of an available framework/API? I've been looking at commonly used ones and most of them seem to be in-house work, i.e. EA's FTP games use http://www.play4free.com/en/ 
I'm looking for something like this but available to third parties.

The project is built on the python framework Django with a heavy Javascript frontend if that helps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the following three might meet your needs:

- [The Kongregate Client-side API](http://developers.kongregate.com/docs/api-overview/intro)
- [Mochi Coins API](http://www.mochimedia.com/developers/coins_signup.html) (or a related one from them)
- [Google's In-App Payments](https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/articles/usinginapppayments) (formerly Social Gold)

all from [A look at micro-transactions services for my next game](http://www.over00.com/?p=1296) by Dave Toulouse, who covers his view of the pros and cons of these and a couple others in that post.

Answer (score 4):

Another one to consider is [Stripe](https://stripe.com/). They have an excellent debug mode that will let you test your forms out without charging anybody anything, and they do not require you to store payment information on your own servers, which is a real win.